# Can i use BigDecimal as an id type in hibernate hbm?

Tags: java, hibernate, primary-key, bigdecimal

i am using hibernate. it has id column with 20 precisions as below but of NUMBER type.

NUMBER(38,20) - this is the size given to id column of the table(Oracle database).

This **id is generated by our application**. in entity if i use Float or Double it cannot accommodate 20 precisions. but java.math.BigDecimal can accommodate these many precisions.
but the problem is can i use BigDecimal in hbm as below? will there be any problems? some times i may not send id with precisions. that time will hibernate generates any empty precision and inserts?

```
<id name="someId" column="SOME_ID" type="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
```

Please suggest!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use type="big_decimal". Under no circumstances should you even attempt to use Float or Double for this.